# How do I access a Core Data entity's attributes in code?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've got the following bit of code in one of my methods:

```
...
NSNumber *selectedRecordID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
    if (selectedRecordID == managedObject.contactID) { // this line generates a compiler error
     // do some stuff
     }
```

The indicated line generates the compiler error "Request for 'contactID' in something not a structure or a union." However, 'contactID' is an attribute of the entities retrieved by the fetched results controller, and is present in the @property declarations generated by Core Data.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But 'contactID' is not a property of the base `NSManagedObject` class, it's a property of your own entity class. For the property to be recognized by the compiler, you need to declare the fetched object using the appropriate type, for example:

```
for (MyEntity *managedObject in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
if (selectedRecordID == managedObject.contactID) { 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use KVC and avoid subclassing via:

```
[managedObject valueForKey:@"contactID"];
```